# Paypal Selling Button

Tags: php, html, paypal, paypal-ipn

First of all, sorry for my English.

I have a Website where i sell Fitnesscoachings. There are three different coachings the users can buy, and for each coaching i have created a separate "buy now" paypal button (because the coachings have different prices)

You know, when you click the paypal button, it redirects you to the paypal payment site, where you can choose between "login to paypal" and "dont have a credit card".

So, i loved the option, the users were able to buy the coachings without singing up on paypal.

But now for one week, the second option isn't the same as it was before. When users click the second option, they can still pay with credit card, but they HAVE to register. its very strange. here's a print screen of the current view in paypal:

[image: what the paypal looks like]

I dont want this view anymore, i want the old one back, where the user DIDN'T have to register.

does anyone of you know the problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about PayPal policies and not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to remember that guest checkout is not guaranteed for every transaction. PayPal runs a risk check to determine eligibility for guest checkout. There will be times when guest checkout is not available. This is intended. Here are a few things to make sure guest checkout is offered as often as possible.

- Verified PayPal account
- Confirmed email address
- Guest Checkout enabled(paypal.com->Profile->My selling Tools->Website Preferences->Paypal account optional enabled)
- With Express Checkout their cart must pass "SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole"

If all of these are met and it's not available then PayPal system has decided to disable the guest checkout option for risk reasons.